# "¿De qué color es la camisa?" - What is "De" for?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, gramática

It looks like this sentence can be formed without the "De" so what is it for?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Spanish the complete answer is:

> La camisa es de color azul.

You can not make it a word by word translation into English. This is simply how it is in Spanish: when you're talking about the color property of a thing it is always constructed as "`<thing> is of <such> colour`".

Of course the answer is usually (but not always) shortened as:

> La camisa es azul.

which relates better to the English way "`<thing> is <colour name>`".

Knowing which the complete answer is, now we can figure out how the correct question is, which turns to be:

> ¿De qué color es la camisa?

"`Which colour is <thing> of?`"

Comment: You broke it down very well. +1 and accepted.

Answer (score 6):

Some of the other answers provide solid practical information, but I'm going to get into some of the nitty gritty of it :)

When you say *La camisa es azul*, you have three parts: subject, copula verb, and predicate adjective.  Here's it and some others broken down:

- El libro<sub>*suj.*</sub> parece<sub>*v.cop.*</sub> interesante<sub>*p.adj.*</sub>.
- La sopa<sub>*suj.*</sub> está<sub>*v.cop.*</sub> fría<sub>*p.adj.*</sub>.
- La camisa<sub>*suj.*</sub> es<sub>*v.cop.*</sub> azul<sub>*p.adj.*</sub>.

Now, here's where it gets interesting (actually, probably more so in English).  What questions would you ask to get the answers of *interesante*, *fría*, and *azul*?  Being adjectives, you *cannot* use *qué* (which replaces nouns).  Your question word must be *cómo*:

- ¿Cómo parece el libro?  Parece interesante.
- ¿Cómo está la sopa?  Está fría.
- ¿Cómo es la camisa?  Es azul.

If we want to limit our answer field a bit, we can add in *de + categoría* (which can be placed really anywhere in the question)

- ¿Cómo parece el libro *de calidad*?
- ¿Cómo está la sopa *de temperatura*?
- ¿Cómo es la camisa *de color*?

Another way to ask these questions, since the answer will inevitably be a type of these categories is to use this *de qué + categoría* structure:

- ¿De qué calidad parece el libro?  Parece *de (una) calidad interesante*
- ¿De qué temperatura está la sopa?  Está *de (una) temperatura fría.*
- ¿De qué color es la camisa?  Es *de (un) color azul*.

When you use *ser* with predicative nominatives (nouns) instead of adjectives, you basically say that the subject is a type of the predicate (or reverse, or literally equals), rather than carries the attribute of the predicate.  *La sopa es una comida*, *El libro es un texto escrito*, *La camisa es una prenda*.

This is hard to see with *La camisa es azul* because azul is technically ambiguous, but always interpreted as adjectival.  Let's force the noun interpretation:  *La camisa es el azul*.  Whoa, that sounds weird.  We can say *El azul es un color* or *Un/el color es el azul*, likewise we can say *Una/la camisa es una prenda* or *Una/la prenda es una/la camisa*.  But with ser, we can't mix and match because they aren't of the same conceptual category.

When you ask *¿Qué color es la camisa?*, *qué* substitutes for a noun, which means the only interpretation is this weird *La camisa es el azul* thing that makes no sense.  You can only ask *¿Qué color es ...?* if what replaces the … is something identifiable as a color (such as *¿Qué color es esto?* and I'm pointing at a solid bit of color somewhere).

A better question might be why English doesn't let you say *What temperature *is* the soup?* but does let you ask *What color *is* the shirt?*

Comment: Great answer. Never thought of it like that. And I'm sure English *does* let you say "What temperature is the soup".

Comment: @0x499602D2 it sounds weird to me (I'm a native), I would say "What's the temperature *of* the soup?" or "What temperature is the soup *at*?", but that may just be me.  Consider, perhaps, "What height is the boy?"

Comment: Okay. Those comparisons made it clear. :)

Answer (score 4):

Bueno, pues no comento porque necesito más reputación, así que lo pongo como "respuesta".
Esa pregunta se puede responder de dos maneras:

> ¿De qué color es la camisa? - Es azul.
>
> ¿De qué color es la camisa? - Es **de** color azul.

La primera respuesta es sólo una manera abreviada de decir la segunda.

---

Well, as I can't comment because I need more reputation, I will put it as a "reply". That question can be answered in two ways:

> ¿De qué color es la camisa? - Es azul.
>
> ¿De qué color es la camisa? - Es **de** color azul.

The first answer is only an abbreviated way to say the second.

Answer (score 2):

If you really don't want the initial "*de*", I guess you might say:

> *¿ Qué color es el color de la camisa ?*

However, that would mean you see the color but can't name it.

Answer (score 1):

A translation of the previous answer:

"Bueno, pues no comento porque necesito más reputación, así que lo pongo como "respuesta". Esa pregunta se puede responder de dos maneras:

¿De qué color es la camisa? - Es azul.

¿De qué color es la camisa? - Es de color azul.

La primera respuesta es sólo una manera abreviada de decir la segunda."

Broadly...
"Well, as I can't comment because I need more reputation, I will put it as a "reply". [the same goes for me!] That question can be answered in two ways:

¿De qué color es la camisa? - Es azul.

¿De qué color es la camisa? - Es de color azul.

The first answer is only an abbreviated way to say the second."

My way of understanding is that "de" is used in the question because the answer is selected from a list (the list of colours) - "Of what colour is the shirt"

Answer (score 0):

"¿De qué color es la camisa?" literally translates into: "OF what color is the shirt?" That just happens to the Spanish construction. We don't need the "of" in English, but we do in Spanish.

"¿De qué color es la camisa?"  se traduce literalmente en: "OF what color is the shirt?" Ese es la construccion española. No necessitamos "of" en ingles, pero lo necesitamos en español.